# How to work with word files in javascript

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js, office-addins, word-web-addins

I want to make a form for uploading word files and processing them.
Connecting microsoft office api:

```
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then I add an event on pressing the button:

```
    function processFile(file) {
    Office.initialize = function () {
        Word = Office.context.word;
    };

    Word.run(function (context) {

        var body = context.document.body;
        context.load(body, 'text');
        return context.sync().then(function () {

            console.log(body.text);
        });
    })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
            if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
            }
        });
}

    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
    
        var fileInput = document.getElementById('wordfile');
        var file = fileInput.files[0];
    
        processFile(file);
    });
```

.
When I click the button, I get an error: caught ReferenceError: Word is not defined.

How to solve this problem or maybe there are libraries in npm to interact with word files?
I need as much detail as possible about the word file (font, text, indentation, table of contents, etc.)

The structure of the project is simple:
/-index.html
/-index.js

Answer (score 0):

The [Office.Context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.context?view=common-js-preview) interface doesn't have the word property. Instead, try to use the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.context?view=common-js-preview#office-office-context-document-member) or [host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.context?view=common-js-preview#office-office-context-host-member) properties instead. For example:

```
// Extension initialization code.
let _document;

// The initialize function is required for all add-ins.
Office.initialize = function () {
    // Checks for the DOM to load using the jQuery ready method.
    $(document).ready(function () {
    // After the DOM is loaded, code specific to the add-in can run.
    // Initialize instance variables to access API objects.
    _document = Office.context.document;
    });
}
```